# Take to hospital or take to the hospital?

Tags: articles

Which is correct:

1. He was taken to hospital?
2. He was taken to the hospital?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This really does not meet this site's standards for an appropriate question. We do have a sister site that might be better suited to your needs, however. Please check out [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The 1st is spoken in BrE and the 2nd in AmE. And @erich is right.

Comment: Thanks so much!  So it means both are right, I am going to write an article about some grammar subject which is the most suitable to use?

Comment: It means _one or the other_ is right, depending on the target audience.